# viewpager + picasso + photoview issue

Tags: android, android-viewpager, picasso, android-photoview

There are 2 issue that I am facing when using viewpager with picasso library and photoview library.

1) Some of the images don't zoom, rather sometimes the next image is zoomed instead.

2) Sometimes when I zoom an image, then adjacent image is also zoomed along with the current one .

How do I solve the above 2 issues?

```
public class ImageViewerPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements PhotoViewAttacher.OnViewTapListener {


Context context;
private int count;
private ArrayList<String> images;
private PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;
private boolean shouldFit = false;


public ImageViewerPagerAdapter(Context context, int count, ArrayList<String> images, boolean shouldFit) {
    this.context = context;
    this.count = count;
    this.images = new ArrayList<>(images);
    this.shouldFit = shouldFit;

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}


@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((FrameLayout) object);
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    String imageUrl = images.get(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_image_viewpager_layout, container, false);
    final PhotoView imageView = (PhotoView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    if (shouldFit) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

                if (mAttacher != null) {
                    mAttacher.update();
                } else {
                    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
                    mAttacher.setOnViewTapListener(ImageViewerPagerAdapter.this);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });
    } else {
        Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                if (mAttacher != null) {
                    mAttacher.update();
                } else {
                    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
                    mAttacher.setOnViewTapListener(ImageViewerPagerAdapter.this);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });
    }

    container.addView(view);


    return view;
}


@Override
public void onViewTap(View view, float v, float v1) {
    Toaster.make(context,"hello");
    ((ImageViewPagerActivity) context).animateToolbar();
}


}
```

Comment: Why are you sharing a single PhotoViewAttacher? Shouldn't each PhotoView object should have its own PhotoViewAttacher?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with Android OS. When OS draw view it will cache it in system, when system request the same view OS will not draw new one instead it retrieve already drawed ones from cache.Thats why you can encounter problems like next image displayed in view. You can see problems like this in list also